# How to access function parameter in asynchronous callback?

Tags: ios, swift

I pass a parameter `uid` to my function `checkIfUserExists` and make an async call. However I am unable to access `uid` within the callback of the async call.

```
class Database {
    func checkIfUserExists(uid: String){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, err) in
            if let document = snapshot, document.exists {
                print("User exists")
            } else {
                print("User does not exist, createUser()")
                createUser(uid: uid) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Call to method 'createUser' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

Any idea how I access `uid` or pass it to the async call so I can pass it to `createUser()`?

Comment: The issue is not uid, but `createUser`. Simply prepend `self.` to the `createUser` call and the compiler should be happy. You might however have to check wether you want to have a weak reference to self, as doing the above implies you want a strong reference.

Comment: Thanks this was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you `createUser` requires `self` since you're capturing the Database instance inside your closure.

`self.createUser` should solve your problem but you should consider if you need to add `[weak self] in (snapshot, err) in` to your closure to prevent a retain cycle.